# in GWT or GWTP, how to export the html page so that the Graphic Design Team can do their work without exposing the source code to them?

Tags: html, gwt, gwtp

Ok, I am building a web app using Gwtp. All software development processes were done online, there's no face to face contact & the source code should not be exposed to someone who are not in programming team.

Now it's a time for graphic Design team to look into html codes (html, css) to build the layout. However, i do not want to export all the javascript or java code to them.

It means it won't work when the graphic designer click on the button, but he can feel free to change all the layout.

So how to export html pages so that the Graphic Design Team can do their work without exposing the source code to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UiBinder, you can send the source XML to designers and have them customize it. That's the easiest way.

The second option would be to give IDs to all your elements. Then give the designer a test site they can access. While they crawl through the generated source they will write CSS based on the '#' sign. They can also override existing CSS and send you their work. You'll just have to put their CSS in your code.

You'll have some problems with images though, since GWT handles images in a particular way, and generates sprites for you.

Also, you won't be able to enjoy the benefit of using ResourceBundles.

Anyway, despite those downsides, designers might not be not ready to crawl through java code and might prefer using plain CSS.

Comment: can u detail it?
How to use UiBinder to send the source XML to designers ?

Comment: ??? By email ! With GWT you rarely use HTML tag. But you can use XML and map it to your java code as explained here http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html. If you write GWT code to generate your page instead of using UIBinder you must give your Java source to the guys.